# React-native-firebase error after first build

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am developing a cross platform application for Android and iOS and have chosen to use react-native-firebase. I have cloned the project from react-native-firebase free starter kit. When I build my application the first time using "npm run android" it works fine but the second time I get the error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Failed to delete: C:\\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug

To run the application again in the Android Studio emulator I have to manually delete the build folder and run "npm run android" again so it can create a new one. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: go to android folder and open terminal and type  gradlew clean . And then rebuild and run again.

Comment: This has been a consistent issue for me building RN apps for Android on Windows. Cleaning the build folder fixes it temporarily. Does anyone know if the RN folks care to fix this permanently or if it is being tracked anywhere?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Though, as a workaround, I don't clean the build folder : I start again the build (react-native run-android) and it goes live.

I may have to start several times.

So that means that the problem is about synchronization in the build process.
I've tried to set in my gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.parallel=false
org.gradle.workers.max=1
```

Till now it works fine!